# Rails 3 current site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey there I am using devise authentication for my rails app and I am aware that I can use the helper `current_user` to access current user in my model or controller. Where I am lost is how can I find the site_id that a user owns. If i look in the active records I can see the users site id. Also I am using the subdomains app from [github](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-subdomains) so my code is identical at the moment.

How can I create a method that tells rails to get the users site_id that is logged in?

Comment: Can't you just access it by calling `current_user.site_id`?

Comment: dont think so because user has a site and site has a blog. When creating a blog post I would like to capture the site_id of the blog.

Comment: You said that the user model has a `site_id` attribute, and `current_user` returns a user model, so by the transitive property, `current_user` should have a `site_id` attribute, right?  Give it a try.

Comment: ok worked fine but it worked using `current_user.site`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that the user model has a `site_id` attribute, and `current_user` returns a user model, so by the transitive property, `current_user` should have a `site_id` attribute, right?

Apparently you can also access the `site` object itself by using `current_user.site`.